# Drag CMDIChildWnd using client area

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to create a `CMDIChildWnd` without title bar draggable using the mouse on the client area.

into the message map I've added

```
ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
```

and

```
void CChildFrame::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    SendMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE | 0x0002);
}
```

the result is a child windows that moves using the mouse as required but only inside its area.

*Any idea on how I can proceed?*

Comment: Can you clarify what 'but only inside its area' means?

Comment: this means the effect that I have is a CMDIChildWnd that can be moved inside its own border and not inside the CMDIFrameWnd like if you use the mouse on the titlebar,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a little trick. The class to implement the behaviour is the derived class of the CFormView and I'm able to move the window as expected sending the htcaption message to the parent

```
void derived_CFormView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CFormView::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);

    GetParentFrame()->PostMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y));
}

void derived_CFormView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CFormView::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    GetParentFrame()->PostMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y));
}
```